Do you back-shift the tense if <present perfect> + <present perfect>
Could someone clarify if the tense should be back-shifted when the main clause is present perfect.

A: James has already watched the film.
B: James has already emailed me about it.
A+B (without backshifting)
=> James has already emailed me that he has already watched the film... is this correct?
=> Or should "has watched" be backshifted, because James had watched the film earlier than the time when he emailed me?
I see a lot of examples like: "James 'emailed' me that he 'had watched' the film."
However, I can't find any examples when it comes to (present perfect) x (present perfect), and believe I need your help.
Thank you very much :)

I’d say past perfect is only called upon when the main verb is already in past (simple, continuous, or perfect). In this case past simple might work the best—I’d consider that one shift back from present perfect. So: “James has already emailed me that he watched the film.” In the example you mentioned where the main verb is past simple, I think either present or past perfect (or past simple) could work (“James emailed me that he watched / has watched / had watched the film”) depending on the timeframe.

No one could imagine that James wrote about a film he saw in the future. He saw it, then he wrote. Period. So if you don't need "had watched the film," you don't use it to get fancy. You also don't need already already in one sentence.

You can probably get along perfectly well in American English if you never use a perfect tense.

How could it hurt to drop both instances of 'already'?

Thanks guys for your responses :)
Firstly, I deliberately left the 2 x the repetitive words of "already", just in order to clarify that James's both actions are completed ones (nothing is ongoing), being aware that it would be an ugly sentence.

I want to say that using 2 present perfect is like Jame is writing the letter while he is watching the movie . It likes right after the movie finish , he clicks the send button immediately . It is kind of weird to me. The normal order should be ''James 'emailed' me that he 'had watched' the film ''. It is more sensible to me.

Thanks for your help.
It is great to know that using 2 x present perfects sounds weird.  Could I ask you an incidental question to your answer?
What if you'd like to emphasize that James has emailed me JUST NOW, and you want to use present perfect for Event B (email) instead of simple past?
How does Event A (James has already completed watching, not ongoingly) should be treated?
Thanks!

'James has already emailed me that he watched the film' this is the sentence I would suggest because it emphasize the action 'email' just happened right now and the action ' watch' has already completed in the past

Thanks a lot.  Cheers :)
